# Restoring my windows 10 into a new partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, restore

I would like to install a new install of windows onto a new partition on my hard drive since the old install of windows is full of viruses.

I don't have a USB key, is there a way to restore windows into a new hard drive partition? I have a prebuilt computer ~2018 with a windows 10 installation that has recovery partition that I feel like should be able to do this without creating a new
USB thing.

Comment: You can perform a Reset from within Windows or use an Windows installation media. I would boot to the installation media

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading this @Ramhound .. it looks like he wants to keep data from his original partition.. create a new partition on the same drive and re-install a new copy of windows there.. all without an external boot device.  Short answer is NO.  You *could* resize your partition down (with the right tools).. make a new partition/volume and copy out what you want to save.. then run the reset as Ramhound suggests.. PITA and not feasible if you had to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks, you got it. Basically my only choice is to make a USB boot thingie?

Comment: So what about the virus problem? There is a high chance that it will still be the same if you don't use separate media to install windows. The recovery partition might also be infected. 

I highly suggest doing a clean install with a bootable USB with an ISO directly from Microsoft, update Windows Defender, and copy your files back.

Comment: @joween really? The virus can get into the recovery partition too? I thought doing a new install would fix it. Thanks, I'll do a clean install then.

Comment: Not a "high chance".. but still a chance.